# Does pasta boiled in tap water absorb chemicals?

Tags: pasta, chemistry

Apparently chlorine goes with boiling but I'm not sure if this is true.  However I know that chloramines also exists in tap water and concentrate more with boiling.

Will the chloramines absorb into the pasta?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, as a chemist i can assure you that whatever chemicals are in the water would tend to get absorbed into the pasta.

In general the public is lousy at assessing risks. Did you drive to store to buy the pasta? You're at a more significant risk of a car accident than a serious problem from chloramines.